# Correlation of two variables with simple regression - what does the distribution of the data points indicate?

Tags: python, regression, correlation

I'm currently doing a correlation analysis of two variables with OLS regression. I have two graphs, which both indicate positive correlation (see pic).

The data points at one of the plots are not as close to the regression line, compared to the other one. I read a lot about this now and most articles and papers explain how strong/weak correlation is indicated in Pearson correlation.

I'm a bit confused now, is it correct, that more distributed data points indicate a weaker correlation (and vice versa) with OLS regression? I'm happy for every hint!

KR!

[image] -> strong correlation?

[image] -> weaker correlation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The closer the points are to the regression line, the stronger the correlation. This is because when they are closer, the deviation of the data is less and the line more accurately represents the data indicating a stronger correlation. The opposite is also true (more spread out points = weaker correlation).